# mysqldump with exec.Command results in 1045 error, but works fine from terminal

Tags: mysql, go

cmd init

```
cmd := exec.Command("mysqldump",
        "--column-statistics=0",
        "--default-character-set=utf8",
        "-P", port,
        "-h", host,
        "-u", username,
        fmt.Sprintf("-p'%s'", password),
        dbname)
```

error text i get

> mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface
>   can be insecure. mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
>   'user'@'ipaddress' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

cmd.String() output

> /usr/bin/mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --default-character-set=utf8
>   -P port -h host -u username -p'password' dbname

when I execute cmd.String() output in terminal on same machine, everything works as expected.
What reasons can be for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an anonymous user `''@'localhost'` or `''@'127.0.0.1'`.

run `mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` to see what users you have on mySQL.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html):

> When multiple matches are possible, the server must determine which of
>   them to use. It resolves this issue as follows: (...)
>
> When a client attempts to connect, the server looks through the rows
>   [of table mysql.user] in sorted order. The server uses the first row
>   that matches the client host name and user name. (...) The server uses
>   sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific Host values
>   first. Literal host names [such as 'localhost'] and IP addresses are
>   the most specific.

Note: an empty string acts a wildcard in MySQL's authentication algorithm

Comment: You should though lookup for others who have this problem before posting the question, just saying...

Comment: There is anonymous user, but I connect to database not on localhost. Host in entry for my user in user table looks like 1.1.%. And ip of the server, from which I am connecting, looks like 1.1.2.3. So there should be a match